# Perl make a SELECT query and return array of objects

Tags: sqlite, perl, dbi

I want to make a query to a sqlite database and return an array of objects.

I'm creating a telegram bot and i have to store the date of last message per user_id, because telegram API returns messages i've already read. So i've created a sqlite db with two tables: users and messages; users contains all the user_id and username; messages contains the last message_id i've read.

I've done this function, it works but it isn't performing very well because it has to recreate the entire array of objects (fetchrow_hashref).

```perl
sub sqlLiteSelect {
    my ($db,$table,$columnsRef,$where,$others) = @_;
    my $columns = join(', ', @{ $columnsRef });
    $others ||= '';
    my $query = "select ${columns} from ${table} ${where}${others}";
    my $obj = $db->prepare($query);
    my $ret = $obj->execute() or die $DBI::errstr;
    my @array = ();
    while(my $row = $obj->fetchrow_hashref) {
        my $tmp = {};
        foreach my $column (@{ $columnsRef }) {
            $tmp->{$column} = $row->{$column};
        }
        push @array, $tmp;
    }
    return @array;
}

my @columns  = ('user_id','first_name','username','type');
my $where = ' where user_id in (1,2)';
my @result = sqlLiteSelect($db,'users',\@columns,$where,'');
foreach my $row (@result) {
    print "user_id=$row->{user_id}, username=$row->{username}\n";
}
```

I expect my select to return an array of object without recreate it everytime.

Comment: Why do you copy each column to `$tmp` instead of directly pushing `$row`?

Comment: I thought it could help to understand what I wanted to achieve

Comment: `push @array, $row;` isn't clear enough?

Comment: Maybe you are right, but maybe not everyone knows what fetchrow_hashref returns...

Comment: [Documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#fetchrow_hashref) exists for a reason...

Comment: You're making an unnecessary copy of a hash in likely the slowest possible way. Get rid of that and see if it still runs too slow.

Comment: That's not the point...i don't understand why you are focusing about this. If the query returns 100k rows like that i've to recreate 100k items in my array. I'm pretty sure this isn't the way to do what i wanted.

Comment: @Loris, there are a few things going on here, in your code and in the comments. The people here pretty much know what they are talking about. I understand your concern about the 'what if' and 100k records. There are ways to avoid what you think is wasteful recreation. But pushing out 100k records in an array of hashreferences is not an issue. If that is what you are worried about, then you should nor loop with a `while` over a `fetch row_hashref` – using yet another loop to build the hashref – to build the huge list and then loop with a `foreach` to print the entire list.

Comment: Either use after the `execute` `return fetchall_arrayref({})` ... that will produce the entire list as nice hashrefs, exactly as you have now, but let smart DBI do all the annoying work for you

Comment: Or if you are so much concerned about recreation and speed: change the entire structure. do a `prepare`, `execute`, `bind_columns(\$user_id, \$first_name, \$username, \$type)` and then straight do `while ($sth->fetch) { print "$user_id $username\n }` forget about the entire subroutine that did create the entire list first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```perl
my ($user_id, $first_name, $username, $type);

my $sql = q{
SELECT user_id, first_name, username, type
  FROM users
 WHERE user_id IN (1,2)
};

my $sth = $db->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute or die $DBI::errstr;
$sth->bind_columns(\$user_id, \$first_name, \$username, \$type);

while ($sth->fetch) {
    print "$user_id, $username\n";
}
```

read the documentation https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#bind_columns

Comment: First thank you for your replies. I had already saw this way, but as i had already said i was searching for something like [{},{}, ...] if possible. Anyway, from the messages you wrote before, i understand this one is the best option. Thank you for your time. I take this as "accepted answer".